# unable to activate hidden administrator on windows 8.1 using cmd prompt

Tags: windows-8.1

I have been trying to enable the hidden Administrator account with higher privileges on Windows 8.1 using a cmd prompt (*as administrator*).

I tried : `net user administrator /active:yes`

I  get the an error saying the user is not recognised / there is no such user!

Does anybody know why this happens and how to resolve this problem?

Comment: if you run `net user`, does it show administrator in the list ?

Comment: It is possible that the administrator user is translated to your local language and thus the name is different. `net user` will show you the correct name. If there's no user at all, then it somehow got deleted.

Comment: Please provide more specific details about your installation.  Are you doing this from within Windows or WinRE.  Have you tried the other methods to enable it?  See my recent answer on this subject for some suggestions

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! I used English instead of my local language... it working now as it should, the hidden administrator account is now visible when logging out!

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this way also

Right-click on My Computer icon on Desktop and select "Manage", it'll open "Computer Management" window.

OR
 "compmgmt.msc" command in RUN dialog box or Start Menu Search box).

Go to "Local Users and Groups -> Users" section. In right-side pane double-click on "Administrator" account. It'll open its Properties window. 
Uncheck "Account is disabled" option and Apply it